# How to display the alert after installation of application in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, installation, alert

I want to display the alert with two options whenever the application will open at first time after completion of installation in Xamarin.Forms.

I want to display that alert one time only, not every time whenever application opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. First install **`Xamarin.Essentials`** package from nuget package manager and use `Preferences` to save `bool` data to know if app already opened or not

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    bool isDispalyed = Preferences.Get("isDisplayed", false);

    if (isDispalyed == false)
    {
        //display alert, first time app starting
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Success", "Saved", "OK");
        });
        Preferences.Set("isDisplayed", true);
    }
    else
    {
        //From second time onward app starting
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.Can you please tell me where I have to implement this code.

Comment: You can write this code in MainPage's `OnAppearing` method.

Comment: " bool isDispalyed = Preferences.Get("isDisplayed", false);"

can u please explain mentioned line once.i can't understand the code.where I have to display my alert for one time after installation the application

Comment: When your app starting first time, `Onapearing` method getting called, it will check `Preference` value, if false` means value not available(display alert). Now you will insert value `true`. When second time app start if will get `Preference` value. If true value is there means app starting from second time.

Comment: On that line of code you are checking if app Preference has value or not. If not means app stating first time. false is default value.

Comment: I understood.Thanks for your explanation and it's working.

Comment: Glad it helped you :)